# Excel Interop freeze panes fails when splitrow is >0

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net

I am trying to freeze panes in an excel worksheet created in a vb.net project. I have created the following test code:

```
Dim xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Dim xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
Dim xlWindow = xlApp.Windows(1)
   
With xlApp.ActiveWindow
  .SplitColumn = 1
  .SplitRow = 0
End With

xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

The problem is that this works fine as written, but if I alter the .SplitRow to anything greater then 0 I get an error on the freezepanes line -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to set the FreezePanes property of the Window class

I have also tried replacing the with block completely with the single line:

```
xlSheet.Cells(6, 2).Select()
```

This doesn't throw an error, but it also only freezes column 6.

I would add that this is an older program that I use once a year and it worked fine last year but I have since upgraded to office 365 (64 bit version). I am still using the interop assembly for office 15 but have not been able to find an updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one has been able to answer this question and I have found a workaround I thought I would post an answer for anyone else who is having this problem. I am not accepting this answer though because there ought to be a solution using microsoft's own dll.

I have found a free dll called spire office by e-iceblue which will allow excel files to be manipulated without office being installed (which makes it version agnostic). There are limitations on the free version but they don't seem to apply to xls files only conversion tasks. This is able to split the panes.